# Is Ubuntu a European Union standard?

Tags: networking, server, system-installation, system, file-server

I mean, is the EU using ubuntu as the main operating system for its IT systems?
I had read somewhere a while ago that this was the case?

I am looking at pushing ubuntu as a file server for a small network at local enterprise and this information would be very useful to my argument.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is not the case. Some public institutions have indeed deployed Ubuntu, but that is far from being the norm. Nonetheless, you should be able to find useful information to back your arguments in [Canonical's Case Studies page](http://www.canonical.com/about-canonical/resources/case-studies).